# Python tricks that can be used in java

Tags: java, string, indexing

Just the little things in python that I love, I'm unfamiliar how to do them in java and I would appreciate any help.

string equivalence:

`Hello` in `hello123` would print true, but in java I only know of `.equals()`, not in.

Is there any way to obtain all java methods what can be used on a string, in python you can just type help(list), and it will tell you everything you can do to lists that are inbuilt.

Comment: `String#contains`, but Java is case sensetive, so you'd need to use `toLower/UpperCase` to convert the two `String`s to the same case

Comment: This is the java 7's String documentation page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

Comment: Thanks .contains() is useful :D, but is there a nice help method?

Comment: @mich there is no "help" tool. All classes from the jdk have published javadoc - just google for it.